# C# Static Methods Calls

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a static method that can be used in chaining, but the available options depend of the previous method within the chain

For example
MethodXX will only be an option if MethodA() was called.

something.MethodA().MethodXX();

If MethodB was called, then the available option will be MethodYY

something.MethodB().MethodYY();

Thank you

Comment: Each method should return it's own type/interface. Which problem did you encounter?

Comment: You appear to be trying to create a fluent interface using static methods. This is impossible as fluid interfaces depend on returning the current object instance.

Static methods don't have access to the current instance.

Comment: @RobertMoskal A fluent interface is not *defined* as an object that returns itself. That's just *one* (extremely poor) way of creating a fluent interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [Fluent Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

You need to return different type with different methods

**Exemple:**

```
    public ReturnTypeB void MethodA(this TypeA)
    {
        //do work
        return ReturnTypeB;
    }
    public ReturnTypeC void MethodB(this ReturnTypeB)
    {
        //do work
        return ReturnTypeC;
    }
```

Comment: This works fine, thanks